# Doxygen autolink not working to global enum types

Tags: doxygen

I am trying to use Doxygen [Automatic link generation](http://www.doxygen.nl/autolink.html) to document some `enum` types. However,  it is not generating links for the global `enum` types. It does generates links for the global `struct` types. Is there something I am missing? I am using the example provided on the link above. As required, I have documented the file in which the types are defined.

**update1**: I am using Doxygen version 1.6.3

**update2**: global structs are ok

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah, I had that same issue; i think doxygen thinks they are private or something stupid like that. Try using the `\public`. Don't forget to do the `/*!` on the first line

```
/*! \public
 * Enum description goes here
 */
typedef enum {

    /**
     * Printer control language ZPL
     */
    PRINTER_LANGUAGE_ZPL,

    /**
     * Printer control language CPCL
     */
    PRINTER_LANGUAGE_CPCL

} PrinterLanguage;
```

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue. Some header files generated a link for enums and other header files did not. You must explicitly document the file.

Here is a excerpt from this page int the documentation.
http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/docblocks.html#memberdoc

> To document a global C function, typedef, enum or preprocessor
>   definition you must first document the file that contains it (usually
>   this will be a header file, because that file contains the information
>   that is exported to other source files).
>
> Attention
>       Let's repeat that, because it is often overlooked: to document global objects (functions, typedefs, enum, macros, etc), you must
>   document the file in which they are defined. In other words, there
>   must at least be a
>
> ```
> /*! \file */ 
>
> or a
>
> /** @file */ 
>
> line in this file.
> ```